# i want to store array value in different variable

Tags: php

I have array that contain 7 string value.
I want to store it in different variable.
but i have 10 variable so i wish that, the variable not contain any array value that's value is zero.

```
<?php 
$str = ("my", "name" , "ajay "," and "," i "," am ", " vageration " );
?>
```

i want to get this string value like

```
$a1=
$a1=my
$a3=name
$a4=ajay
$a5=and
$a6=i
$a7=am
$a8=vageration
$a9=0
$a10=0
```

i don`t know how can i print this value

Comment: you mean "vegetarian"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I wont answer to your question, but I don't really understand what you want.

If you want to dynamically assign variables in php, I could invite you to do something like that:

```
<?php
$str = ("my", "name" , "ajay "," and "," i "," am ", " vageration " );
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    ${'a'.$i} = (isset ($str[$i]) ? $str[$i] : 0);
?>
```

In your case, this will create the following variables :

```
<?php
$a0 = "my";
$a1 = "name";
$a2 = "ajay ";
$a3 = " and ";
$a4 = " i ";
$a5 = " am ";
$a6 = " vageration ";
$a7 = 0;
$a8 = 0;
$a9 = 0;
?>
```

This line (`${'a'.$i} = (isset ($str[$i]) ? $str[$i] : 0`) uses the ternary operator, which means that the variable `${'a'.$i}` will have `$str[$i]`'s value if such a value exists or `0` otherwise.

Not sure it helps. I'll edit or delete my message if necessary.

Comment: actually, i want to 10 variable ...  Here i get 6 variable with value. i want to get 4 mor variable that automatically get value '0'. example. if foreach print 4 variable. then i want to 6 more variable that value '0'..     In short word - i want to 10 variable that contain array value and '0' value

Comment: Maybe more something like this ?

`<?php for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) ${'a'.$i} = (isset ($str[$i]) ? $str[$i] : 0); ?>`

Where `… ? … : …` is the ternary operator.
Still not sure of what you want.